# How to fix error in "Register.updatePage" at "register.js" in an empty Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***EDIT: The error fixed itself on its own! It only happened on Chrome and only in one of my computers, but now it seems to have desappeared.

I  just created a rails app (as in I have two views and one controller), but when I open any page this error appears:

VM54 register.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')
at Register.updatePage (VM54 register.js:95:25)

And the counter of the error keeps going up and up and up without me doing anything. Then if I click a button with a link_to another  path it throws:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'STATUS_REGISTERED' has already been declared (at register.js:1:1)

And then starts stacking the first error all over again.
In my project I don't have any file named "register.js", so I don't know where it's coming from.

And here it's a picture
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdq54.png)

I don't understand where the error is coming from, my app has barely anything in it.

Comment: I just grabbed your app and ran it locally, no error. Try in an incognito window - maybe a browser extension playing up or something?

Comment: Hello! I realized earlier today that copying the repository in another computer didn't show the same error. I'm still looking for what may not be working properly, though it doesn't seem to affect the performance of the site. Thank you for trying!

Comment: No problem. Voting to close this.